# Triggering change events in a loop results in loss events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am triggering a change event on a combo box for multiple values but unfortunately events are getting lost. Is there a way to wait for one event to complete before triggering the next event. Sample code is shown below

```
        for (i = 0; i < contextFilters.length; i++)
        {
            var contextFilter = contextFilters[i];
            if (contextFilter != "")
            {
                var cfData = contextFilter.split(":");
                var cfName  = cfData[0];
                var cfVal = cfData[1];
                if (cfName != null)
                {
                    //alert("cfName : " + cfName);
                    //alert("cfVal : " + cfVal);
                    $('#context_filter').val(cfName);
                    $('#context_filter').trigger('change', cfVal);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

When the event is triggered a new select box is added to the DOM but not all select boxes are getting added.

Also the change event handler is a s shown below

```
$('#context_filter').change(function(event, selectValues)
{
    if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") > 0)
    {
        populateDateValues();
        var contextFilterComboObject = $(this);
        var selectedVal = $(contextFilterComboObject).val();
        var validate = $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled') == null;
        if (!validate)
        {
            $('table[id*=OtherOptions] :input').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        var formInput = decodeURIComponent($('#rptInputParams').serialize());
        formInput += "&validate=" + validate;
        $('#ajaxBusy').show();
        $.getJSON('GetContextFilterData', formInput, function(data)
        {
            var selectBox = '<tr><td class="celltoppad"><b>' + selectedVal +
                    ' : </b></td> <td class="celltoppad"><select multiple="multiple" name="' +
                    selectedVal.toLowerCase() + '" id="' + selectedVal.toLowerCase() + '" >';
            var errorMsg = '';
            var errorCount = 1;
            errorMsg += '<html>';
            $.each(data.errorMessageList, function(index, value)
            {
                errorMsg += errorCount + ') ' + value + '</br></br>';
                errorCount++;
            });
            errorMsg += '</html>';

            if (errorCount > 1)
            {
                $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
                showErrorDialog(errorMsg, errorCount * 20);
                $(contextFilterComboObject).prop("selectedIndex", '0');
                return;
            }

            $.each(data.contextFilterDataList, function(index, value)
            {
                selectBox += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + "</option>";
            });

            selectBox +=
                    '</select></td><td class="celltoppad"><a href="#"><img id="removeCF" ' +
                            'src="../images/remove.png"/></a></td></tr>';

            $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
            // If the context filter has not been already added.
            if ($('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).length == 0)
            {
                $('a[id*=_showDialog]').hide();
                toggleDatePickerLink();
                $('img#removeDate').hide();
                $('table[id*=OtherOptions] :input').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled', true);
                $('table#context_filter').append(selectBox);                    
                $(contextFilterComboObject).prop("selectedIndex", '0');
            }

            if (selectValues != null)
            {
                $('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).val(selectValues.split(","));
            }

            $('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).multiselect({
                noneSelectedText: 'Please select',
                selectedList: 3,
                selectedText: '# of # selected',
                position: {
                    my: 'left center',
                    at: 'right center',
                    offset: '20 100'
                }
            }).multiselectfilter();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide the `change` event handler

Comment: Please see i have added the change event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution to my problem, when the back button is clicked and the change event is fired then I made the ajax call using async as false and that resolved the issue. This is because if the async is true json calls happen simultaneously and some events are lost during that period.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of triggering the event, can't you just call the handler ?

```
var handler = function(event, selectValues)
{
    if ($('#context_filter').prop("selectedIndex") > 0)
    {
        populateDateValues();
        var contextFilterComboObject = $('#context_filter');
        var selectedVal = $(contextFilterComboObject).val();
        var validate = $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled') == null;
    if (!validate)
    {
        $('table[id*=OtherOptions] :input').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    var formInput = decodeURIComponent($('#rptInputParams').serialize());
    formInput += "&validate=" + validate;
    $('#ajaxBusy').show();
    $.getJSON('GetContextFilterData', formInput, function(data)
    {
        var selectBox = '<tr><td class="celltoppad"><b>' + selectedVal +
                ' : </b></td> <td class="celltoppad"><select multiple="multiple" name="' +
                selectedVal.toLowerCase() + '" id="' + selectedVal.toLowerCase() + '" >';
        var errorMsg = '';
        var errorCount = 1;
        errorMsg += '<html>';
        $.each(data.errorMessageList, function(index, value)
        {
            errorMsg += errorCount + ') ' + value + '</br></br>';
            errorCount++;
        });
        errorMsg += '</html>';

        if (errorCount > 1)
        {
            $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
            showErrorDialog(errorMsg, errorCount * 20);
            $(contextFilterComboObject).prop("selectedIndex", '0');
            return;
        }

        $.each(data.contextFilterDataList, function(index, value)
        {
            selectBox += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + "</option>";
        });

        selectBox +=
                '</select></td><td class="celltoppad"><a href="#"><img id="removeCF" ' +
                        'src="../images/remove.png"/></a></td></tr>';

        $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
        // If the context filter has not been already added.
        if ($('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).length == 0)
        {
            $('a[id*=_showDialog]').hide();
            toggleDatePickerLink();
            $('img#removeDate').hide();
            $('table[id*=OtherOptions] :input').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled', true);
            $('table#context_filter').append(selectBox);                    
            $(contextFilterComboObject).prop("selectedIndex", '0');
        }

        if (selectValues != null)
        {
            $('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).val(selectValues.split(","));
        }

        $('#' + selectedVal.toLowerCase()).multiselect({
            noneSelectedText: 'Please select',
            selectedList: 3,
            selectedText: '# of # selected',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                offset: '20 100'
            }
        }).multiselectfilter();
    });
}
});

    for (i = 0; i < contextFilters.length; i++)
    {
        var contextFilter = contextFilters[i];
        if (contextFilter != "")
        {
            var cfData = contextFilter.split(":");
            var cfName  = cfData[0];
            var cfVal = cfData[1];
            if (cfName != null)
            {
                //alert("cfName : " + cfName);
                //alert("cfVal : " + cfVal);
                $('#context_filter').val(cfName);
        handler(null, cfVal);                       
            }
        }
    }
```

I never tested above code, but I declared your handler as a function and then in the loop at the bottom, you can see how I call it instead of triggering it (handler(cfVal))

Comment: My change event handler is as shown above, how can i call the above handler instead of triggering the event?

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for the explanation, but the behavior remains the same as with the event i.e. say if there are four calls to the handler out of which only 2 or 3 calls are getting successfully achieved rest are getting lost like the events. If i put alert's in the handler function it works perfectly. So, somehow the calls are getting eaten up, is there any solution for the same?

Comment: I am sorry, I aù np jquery expert, I  guess you'll have to debug it or rewrite it to get it to work.